# SIM7600 serial port multiplexer with Beaglebone

Tags: gsm, uart, multiplexing

I am using SIM7600 module with Beaglebone board connected thru UART2. It works well with ppp on /dev/ttyS2.

Since the application wants the GPS info simultaneously, trying to use CMUX with the n_gsm driver as given here 
https://github.com/Rtone/cmux

The modem responds with OK for AT+CMUX=0,0,5,127,0,0,200.
The tty devices for the virtual ports 1 to 4 are created in the linux - /dev/ttyGSM[1-4].
But no serial port utilities work.

Anyone has any experience in this.